# NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest getting call twice

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

In my code i had override NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest to send the cached response in case if downloaded already. But for some reason cachedResponseForRequest getting called twice. Could anybody know the reason?

Is this a default behaviour?

Comment: Did you checked the callstack (you can print it) each times it's called? Just to see which line of code is calling it?

Comment: Since its a internal call, its not visible from stack from where its getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the method in question is called from two different parts of the NSURLSession stack for very different reasons:

- To get the date of the cached response, so that it can provide headers in a HEAD request asking the server if the content has been modified since then.
- To obtain the actual data for the cached response after the server sends back a 304 (NOT MODIFIED) status code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so is there any way stopping this? It seems the way we were preparing cached data, means HTTPURLResponse cahcing never worked it was always going to the server to get the data.

Comment: By default, it goes to the server and asks if it changed, but that's just a HEAD request (not fetching the actual data).  Why do you want to prevent the app from checking if the content has changed?  It would help to understand your goals to provide a better answer.  :-)